# Error: 1600 - cursor not found issue with arango spark datasource when try to fetching enitre collection

Tags: pyspark, arangodb, pyarango, python-arango

I am writing a data pipeline to ingest data from arango db to Bigquery. I have used arango spark data source.

here is the code :

```
 df: DataFrame = spark.read.format("com.arangodb.spark") \
        .option("query", query) \
        .options(**arango_connection) \
        .schema(doc_schema).load()
df.count()
    df.write.format('bigquery').mode("append") \
        .option('table', bq_table) \
        .option("project", bq_project) \
        .option("dataset", bq_dataset) \
        .option("writeMethod", "direct") \
        .option('credentialsFile', 'path/of/gcp-credential') \
        .save()
```

this code is working if my arango collection has fewer documents, like able to write 10000 documents from arango db to Bigquery.

But my collection will have more than 10, 00, 000 (**Millions**) document. When testing with above 50, 000 document spark job is failing.

**error getting **

```
`
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Response: 404, Error: 1600 - cursor not found


org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (BS1ZN93 executor driver): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Response: 404, Error: 1600 - cursor not found
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeTaskCompletionListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 404, Error: 1600 - cursor not found
        at com.arangodb.internal.util.ResponseUtils.checkError(ResponseUtils.java:53)
        at com.arangodb.http.HttpCommunication.execute(HttpCommunication.java:86)
        at com.arangodb.http.HttpCommunication.execute(HttpCommunication.java:66)
        at com.arangodb.http.HttpProtocol.execute(HttpProtocol.java:44)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:60)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:48)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoDatabaseImpl$1.close(ArangoDatabaseImpl.java:219)
        at com.arangodb.internal.cursor.ArangoCursorImpl.close(ArangoCursorImpl.java:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.arangodb.datasource.reader.ArangoQueryReader.close(ArangoQueryReader.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$advanceToNextIter$1(DataSourceRDD.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$advanceToNextIter$1$adapted(DataSourceRDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContext.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.$anonfun$invokeTaskCompletionListeners$1(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.$anonfun$invokeTaskCompletionListeners$1$adapted(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:199)
        ... 10 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:3459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:3458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:3458)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Response: 404, Error: 1600 - cursor not found
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeTaskCompletionListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apac
```

How can this be resolve?

ArangoDb should be return millions for records without cursor error.